# Does "the day that I was born on" have the same meaning as "the day which I was born on"?

Tags: difference, relative-clauses

> "May 19, 2004, was the day______________"
>
> 1. (a) which I was born on
> 2. (b) that I was born on"

Are (a) (b) grammatically correct and accepted by native speakers? I know that I can use " on which I was born" or "when I was born" but do they all have the same meanings?

Comment: Yes, all of them are grammatical and acceptable. The shorter versions are more colloquial, since the relative markers are completely predictable with a temporal clause, and they're normally left out in ordinary  talk. They are deleted grammatically by syntactic rule (aka "transformation", "alternation", etc.), which only change one syntactic pattern to a different one, and never change meaning.

Comment: I think most people would simply say "the day I was born".

Answer (score 1):

- It is true that both the day "*that* I was born on." and the day "*which* I was born on." would be equally understood by native English speakers, particularly in casual speech.
- It is also true that both phrases are equally **grammatically
  incorrect**.

First, "that," "which," and "on" are all prepositions. You only need to use one. As your fill-in-the-blank sentence is worded, the correct wording is the day "**that** I was born." (As was ultimately recommended by https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/165060/edb.)
See the distinction between "that" and "which" as prepositions: https://www.masterclass.com/articles/which-vs-that

Second, if you want to use the preposition "on," and you can rewrite the sentence, write "I was born on May 19, 2004."

Finally, try to place any preposition directly before its object. Placing "on" at the end of the sentence separates it from the date, which puts it in the category of **Preposition Stranding**. See **Scribbr** for more on preposition position.
[https://www.scribbr.com/parts-of-speech/ending-a-sentence-with-a-preposition/#:~:text=Yes%2C%20it's%20fine%20to%20end,results%20in%20very%20unnatural%20phrasings](https://www.scribbr.com/parts-of-speech/ending-a-sentence-with-a-preposition/#:%7E:text=Yes%2C%20it%27s%20fine%20to%20end,results%20in%20very%20unnatural%20phrasings).

Comment: As an example of what @kbrungraber is describing in the last paragraph, if you want to use the preposition 'on' and be completely correct, you could say, '...the day on which I was born.'. If you want to learn English well, I'd suggest you read Charles Dickens.

Comment: According to @dwilli, "If you want to learn English well, I'd suggest you read Charles Dickens." This is not necessarily the case.
Charles Dickens was paid by the word. His stories often first appeared first in parts, published in periodicals. This meant that each published part had to fill a certain number of column inches, a requirement that would encourage any writer to unnecessarily pad their prose.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are correct. When you say **the day I was born on** it is pretty possible to change the position of **on**, either before the clause or after, no change in the meaning. As your former sentence includes word **day** you can use **Which** as you can count the *day*, **That** as it is alternative to *which* in some time, **When** because it is like *time clause marker* and you can use it with *year/month/week/day/...*.
No change in the main meaning of sentence.

When it comes to not using preposition **on**, I think, if you talk about your day of birth, it is clear and no need to use *on*. But it is informal, I think

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).